# abort a window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url say www.abc.com which display all data of a table

I have search box in the page which calls a function search() on keyup

```
//search function
function search(){
    window.location.hash = "?query="+$("#search).val(); /* goes to the page and get data*/
}
```

When I type any key say a, it will send a the request www.abc.com?query=a and get all data starting with a
When I type any key say aa, it will send the request www.abc.com?query=aa and get all data starting with aa

I want to know a way to abort the request www.abc.com?query=a when
www.abc.com?query=aa is send because it takes a lot of time

Comment: If you only change the hash, the page is not reloaded an there's no request. I think you're using ajax for this, because you tagged jquery, am I right?

Comment: little fyi - you are not ending your string `$("#search).val()` should be `$("#search").val()`  if your code has it as it's written here, you'll get runtime errors

Comment: you should post the relevant code you are using, not 'pseudo code' which didn't make sense. BTW, you could debounce a little your search function using a timeout, e.g, send a request if no key has been pressed since 1 second

Comment: @roasted : I think a timeout is a good idea

Comment: @sircapsalot : m getting d right data n sending d tight data missed out " on the above.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever "goes to the page and get data" is, it should return a handle. For instance, if you're using the [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) `XMLHttpRequest`, then you can return that object.

Then, before loading a new search, call its `abort` method to cancel the old one.

Note that this may not actually cancel it on the server side, so be careful.

Comment: I have use Ajax n have tried abort in it. It works fine. Now I want to do it in this method